# Woocommerce product add-ons fields not showing after order completion

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and woocommerce addons plugin. When i try to complete an order everything appears normal. When i am at the final step of the order though, the table with products and addons shows there is an addon but not the name of it, so my client can not see the extra materials in an order (only that they exist and how much they cost). Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What additional plugin are you using? Can you give a link to the web site and add a screenshot? What is that extra material? Have you tried to open a support thread within this additional plugin?

Comment: Have you tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/ plugin.?